# Unity Networking: Object has velocity, but not moving

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking, velocity, rigid-bodies

This is for a 2.5D / orthographic view game. Basically, each player can fire a projectile. this projectile should have a fixed velocity until it hits a target (no drag, no gravity). I originally had this working, though there was a significant amount of lag for non-server players. In order to fix this, I have used an RPC call to instantiate a local 'dummy' projectile for all clients, while the server instantiates and manages the real projectile (with collider, etc). This way the clients to see a laggy projectile (no object is spawned on the server).

I've nearly got it working (network-wise - no lag, appearing correctly), however, all projectiles slow to a standstill for no apparent reason. According to the object rigidbody info section, it still appears to have velocity, but it ain't moving.

here's my code. I want it to work WITHOUT NetworkServer.Spawn(projectile)
if I uncomment this line, the spawned projectile does not lose velocity, while the clients dummy projectile comes to a stop.

Thanks for the help!

```
protected virtual void CreateProjectile() {
    Vector2 mousePos = playerCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    Vector2 myPos = (Vector2)transform.position;
    Vector2 direction = mousePos - myPos;
    direction.Normalize();
    float orientation = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    Vector3 endOfGun = DetermineEndOfWeapon() * 0.7f; // 0.6f because gun doesn't take up entire sprite
    Vector3 endOfGunWorldPos = this.transform.position + endOfGun;

    Cmd_CreateProjectile(endOfGunWorldPos, direction, orientation);
}

[Command]
protected virtual void Cmd_CreateProjectile(Vector2 endOfGunWorldPos, Vector2 direction, float orientation) {

    GameObject projectile = Instantiate(projectilePrefab, endOfGunWorldPos, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    projectile.gameObject.layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("TeamAProjectile");
    projectile.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = direction * projectileSpeed;
    projectile.transform.Rotate(0, 0, orientation);
    projectile.transform.SetParent(projectileParent.transform);
    projectile.name = projectileName;

    // don't want to spawn, just create local projectile for all clients
    //NetworkServer.Spawn(projectile);
    Rpc_CreateDummyProjectile(endOfGunWorldPos, direction, orientation);
}

[ClientRpc]
protected virtual void Rpc_CreateDummyProjectile(Vector2 endOfGunWorldPos, Vector2 direction, float orientation) {
    if (isServer) {
        return;
    }
    // creating dummy bullet for 'laggy' client so it looks good for them
    GameObject dummyProjectile = Instantiate(projectilePrefab, endOfGunWorldPos, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    BoxCollider2D bc2d = dummyProjectile.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
    Destroy(bc2d);

    dummyProjectile.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = direction * projectileSpeed;
    dummyProjectile.transform.Rotate(0, 0, orientation);
    dummyProjectile.transform.SetParent(projectileParent.transform);
    dummyProjectile.name = "DUMMY" + projectileName;
}
```

Comment: CreateProjectile is only called on the server? (please ensure it with the isServer check)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Nope, when mouse clicks, any player should be able to fire a projectile, which means client players also need to call CreateProjectile

Comment: try to make it like: private void CreateProjectile()
{        
    if (isServer)
    {
        Rpc_CreateProjectile();
    }
    else
    {
        Cmd_CreateProjectile()
    }
} And tell me if it improves